# How to determine significance for a Corrado rank test in an event study?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, nonparametric

I apologise if this is a stupid question (it feels stupid tbh). I am currently doing an event study and my abnormal returns are not normally distributed. I am now in the process of performing a Corrado rank test for significance.

As far as I can tell, you take the sum of the ranks for each AR, and compare it to the average of the ranks (so if my T= 111, the average would be 56)

[image]

[image]

What I am confused about is when I compute the test statistic, how exactly do you know if it is significant?